# I can't get into PL/SQL Developer with the user "system" when I set the instant_client

Tags: oracle, plsqldeveloper

I configured instant_client to connect to the database via VPN

[image]

The instant_client path below:

```
C:\Users\mywindows\Documents\instantclient_10_2\oci.dll
```

[image]

But when I configure the instant client, I can no longer login with the system user, so I have to leave the "OCI Library" field blank and that's the only way I can login.

The user "system" I say is from my machine

Can someone help me log into PL with the system user and other users without giving conflicts?

I'm currently using PL/SQL Developer 14.0.6.1988 x64

Windows 10 x64 Enterprise

8gb ram

intel i5 2.50 ghz

Comment: Is it only the system user that can't connect, or all users? Does SQL\*Plus work with the instant client?

Comment: it's just the user "system" if i configure the oci.dll

Comment: I use oci.dll to connect to the company server. But when that happens I can't enter the user "system"

Comment: "doesn't work" and "cannot connect" are devoid of actionable information.  Surely you get some sort of error code/message?

Comment: I don’t have an answer, but is that instant client 10.2, from, what, 2004? I’m surprised that is still available to download. Do you have the same issue with a supported version? This is looking like a product support issue though, I’m afraid.